# Python - CV2 strange behavior on Spyder while processing images

Tags: linux, python-2.7, multidimensional-array, opencv, python

I am working on YOLO network for object detection. I am getting unexpected result while working on images. My findings are:

While drawing rectangle on an image using `cv2.rectangle()` method, it changes the image type as `NoneType` on Spyder IDE, while it remains same (i-e: `numpy.ndarray`) on Jupyter-notebook. 
The code as follows:

```
img = cv2.imread('1527502132336.jpeg', 1)
result = tfnet.return_predict(img)
tl = (result[0]['topleft']['x'], result[0]['topleft']['y'])
br = (result[0]['bottomright']['x'], result[0]['bottomright']['y'])
label = result[0]['label'] 
img = cv2.rectangle(img, tl, br, (255, 0, 0), 3)
type(img)
```

I want to get the same result as returned by Jupyter for further processing. Why I am getting this strange behavior.

Comment: It might have something to do with access to your `'1527502132336.jpeg'` image. Have you made sure that it is available in the working directory for the Spyder version of your code? One way to ensure this isn't a problem is using an [absolute path](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/5817/absolute-path) to your image.

Comment: I am sure its not a path problem as I can access all variable such as **result**, **label** via Spyder. The variables are returning correct values.